# Ultimate Member login Shortcodes for dropdown login form not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I create a drop down button for Wordpress plugin ultimate member login form. It's working correctly inside the content page, but when i paste these codes outside i mean in `header.php` it's not show login form.I'm also using restricted content code of ultimate member.Please any one help me.
Thanks in Advance.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCS6I.jpg)

[Inside content page of wordpress working 100% correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRh07.jpg)

```
    <div style="width:120px; background:lightgrey;" class="ld-en">
<div class="col-md-1"><h4>Hello</h4></div>
<div class="col-md-2">[um_loggedin show_lock=no] <h4 style="color:red;padding-left:15px;">{first_name} </h4>  
    [/um_loggedin]</div>

<div class="col-md-2">[um_loggedout]  <div class="dropdown"> <button class="login-drop dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Log In<span class="caret"></span></button>

     <div class="dropdown-menu login-dropdown"  role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1"> [ultimatemember form_id=287]
<ul class="login-dropdown">
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Register</a></li>    
    </ul></div>
  </div>  [/um_loggedout]</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use do_short_code() for each short code you have used in your file
check this out [check how to use it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)
for example

```
 <div style="width:120px; background:lightgrey;" class="ld-en">
<div class="col-md-1"><h4>Hello</h4></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><?php echo do_shortcode( '[um_loggedin show_lock=no]' ); ?> <h4 style="color:red;padding-left:15px;">{first_name} </h4>  
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[/um_loggedin]') ?></div>
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i cannot do that because i'm beginner on wordpress can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Wordpress shortcodes can be display with `<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode-here]') ?>` in (php) templates